# Ionic e AngularJs: Como filtrar nomes repetidos no ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Como filtrar, com Ionic e AngularJs, nomes repetidos no meu `ng-repeat`? Já usei o `ui.filters` e o `unique` só funciona quando não tem rotas, ou seja, em Websites em aplicativos moveis não funciona.

No meu controller tentei isso:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.filters'])
       .controller("papaRoca", function($scope, Data, $location) { });
```

E na minha *view* coloquei:

```
<div ng-repeat="Lista in Listas | unique:'nome'">...</div>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: ajudaria se você colocasse parte do código do que já fez.

Comment: Leo no meu controller tentei isso angular.module('myApp', ['ui.filters'])
      .controller("papaRoca", function($scope, Data, $location) {

  });   e na minha veia coloquei <ng-repeat = Lista in Listas | unique:'nome'>

Comment: @Dan100, adicione as partes do código direto na sua pergunta, e não nos comentários.

Comment: @Dan100, como é um objeto que está vindo em `Listas`?

Comment: De uma olhada nesta [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35689535/2520523). Deve ter o que vc precisa.

Comment: Cara, eu estou usando ui.filters em um sistema cheio de rotas e está normal.

Comment: Diego vc usa com ionic normal ?

Comment: Olá, Utilize este plugin: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter ai você pode usar o ***| unique:'campo_que_quiser'*** sem criar nada no controller. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
app.filter('unique', function() {

  return function (arr, field) {
    var o = {}, i, l = arr.length, r = [];
    for(i=0; i<l;i+=1) {
      o[arr[i][field]] = arr[i];
    }
    for(i in o) {
      r.push(o[i]);
    }
    return r;
  };
})
```

tente esta função.